# Hide/show ViewPager in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view

I have this app structure:

1. MainActivity with a global menu and `Fragment` container.
2. First `Fragment`:  a `ViewPager` with three pages.
3. Second `Fragment`: a list

I insert the `Fragment`s on the `OnCreate()` in the MainActivity and change their visibility with show and hide (using the `FragmentTransaction`).

When I launch the app the first `Fragment` appear in the screen without problem, when change to the second `Fragment` also work like a charm but when I come back to the first `Fragment` the app doesn't show anything inside the `ViewPager`.

Are there any particular option that I have to change in the `ViewPager` to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems due to that android does not allow to have nested fragments. In my case I can manage the situation using simple views instead of fragments inside the ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

I used [ViewStub](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-with.html) to show/hide ViewPager.

The basic idea was you created ViewStub in layout file, and inflate/setVisible while necessary.

The only trick was, I had to setAdatper to null otherwise it crashed while re-createView when off and on screen.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    viewPager.setAdatper(null);
}
```